# jQuery combobox setting default value after creation

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm having a difficulty using the jQuery combobox widget as mentioned [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox):

I'm using jQuery to load the options for the select using ajax, which means that upon creation of the combobox, there are no options in it. When I get the values from the ajax call, I set the first option to be be selected. This works fine for the underlying select, but not for the input-field which jQuery combobox has added.

I've seen the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749721/how-do-set-a-default-value-with-jquery-autocomplete-combobox) but this will not work if the options are added after _create is called(also, it is kinda outdated since the widget by default handles this).

As far as I can tell, there are no relationsship between the underlying combobox and the input-field that makes the one update the other. Or am i wrong here?

Regards, 
Runar

Comment: Please add your code with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok..solved this myself adding the following code snippet in  _create :

```
        select.change(function() {
        var selected = select.children( ":selected" );
        input.val(selected.val() ? selected.text() : "");
        });
```

Then invoked change on the combo after values had been populated.

Comment: Nice one. I was trying to set a default value and this worked.